# Logical instructions for CIL

Tags: operator-keyword, cil

How can I use logical operators like AND, OR, NOT in CIL ?

Answer (score 3):

There are no CIL opcodes for those operators; you need to implement them via conditional branching instead.  For instance, `a && b` is the same as `a ? b : false`, and `a || b` is the same as `a ? true : b`, both of which are relatively easy to implement in IL (e.g. you can use the `brtrue` opcode to do a conditional jump based on the value of `a`).